Why does the URL constructor not decode the username/password?
URL decodes searchParams:
> [...new URL('http://localhost?foo%40=bar').searchParams][0]
['foo@', 'bar']

Yet for some reason, it doesn't decode username/password:
> new URL('http://jimbo%40gmail.com:%40wesome@localhost').username
'jimbo%40gmail.com'
> new URL('http://jimbo%40gmail.com:%40wesome@localhost').password
'%40wesome'

Obviously I know how to work around this, but does anyone know the rationale why it doesn't decode them?
RFC 3986 section 3.2.1 specifically indicates that the username/password of a URI may be percent-encoded:
userinfo    = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" )

So I would assume this is a bug if it were not a well-standardized API.

I tried figuring this out by searching for all references to percent-encode in the WhatWG spec, but I couldn't find anything specific to this. Interestingly, if you assign an encoded string to url.username, it doesn't re-encode the percent characters.

@Barmar well that's what I would hope, if it encoded in one direction but didn't decode in the other that would be bad

But it does encode in one direction if you give it a character that requires encoding. If you do url.username = 'foo/bar'; it becomes foo%2bar

oh I see, yeah that's worse

It's weird, but not necessarily worse. At least url.username = url.username works as you'd expect. If writing re-encoded percents, this would not be a no-op.

well, it's not great that if you get the value it may not match the string you just set.

What's most important is the resource that's accessed when using the URL. It's not intended to be a general purpose container object. But somewhere they should document that when assigning to these fields you should use an explicit encodeURIComponent() if the value could contain literal text that looks like a percent encoding. Not likely for the username, but passwords could be anything.

Likely for the username too; using email addresses as usernames is common.  Again, if decoding search params is within the purpose of URL (that's pretty "general purpose container" type of usage), it's odd that decoding username/password isn't.

Email addresses don't usually have literal % characters (AFAIK, UUNET addresses are long obsolete), so it's not really an issue for usernames.

What I meant about general purpose containers is that when you assign to a URL property, what you care about is how it acts when fetching the resource. It doesn't matter that you get a different string when you read it out. So assigning url.username = 'foo/bar' and getting foo%2Fbar when you read it shouldn't be a problem, because they both work the same if you call fetch(url).

That's the case if you're only using URL for fetch, but you can also use it just for parsing or constructing URLs for other purposes.  And in those cases, the fact that getter and setter may not agree is potentially surprising

It doesn't matter -- as long as it's self-consistent.

If you want to use these fields in other ways, e.g. to send them to an authentication API, you just need to call decodeURIComponent(). But you don't need to do that with other properties. That's confusing, but as long as you know to do it it's OK.

I imagine if it's not an accident there's a good reason for it, and an interesting lesson to be learned from why they're not decoded automatically

Unless there's a record of the design discussion, I don't think we'll lbe able to get an objecctive "why" answer. So it will be mostly speculation/opinion.

This behavior is not actually a bug, but rather part of the URL Living Standard. It specifies that username and password values ​​in a URL should not be automatically decoded, even if they are percent encoded.
const url = new URL('http://jimbo%40gmail.com:%40wesome@localhost');
const decodedUsername = decodeURIComponent(url.username); // 'jimbo@gmail.com'
const decodedPassword = decodeURIComponent(url.password); // '@wesome'
console.log(decodedUsername, decodedPassword);


I was sure this was the specified behavior, but I'm wanting to understand the rationale for why this behavior is specified. Sorry I should have been clearer in my question
